# how to find substring of string in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can you please tell me how to split string to get out put.

- If I have this string: `'tc_1'` Output is : first String : `'tc_'`  second string: `'1'`
- If I have this string: `'tc_1_tc_1'` Output is : first String : `'tc_1_tc_'`  second string: `'1'`
- If I have this string: `'tc_1_tc_1_tc_2'` Output is : first String : `'tc_1_tc_1_'`  second string: `'2'`

in jQuery ?

I use this

```
var index = id.indexOf("_");
var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length)
```

It works for the first case but does not work in other cases.

Comment: You are considering the problem from the wrong side.

Comment: FYI this isn't a jQuery problem, JavaScript is the language, jQuery is just a library and is not designed to replace simple functions such as those involving string manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
var index = id.lastIndexOf("_");
var count = id.substring(index + 1);
```

Also, you don't need the second argument `id.length` to `substring()`.